# positional index using python

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

Getting started with python. I am trying to implement positional index using nested dictionary. However I am not sure if thats the way to go. Index should contain term/term frequency/doc id/term position.

Example:

`dict = {term: {termfreq: {docid: {[pos1,pos2,...]}}}}`

My question is: am i on the right track here or is there a better solution to my problem. If nested dictionary is the way to go i have one additional question: how do I get single items out of the dictionary: for example term frequency for a term (without all the additional infromation about the term).
Help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each `term` seems to have a term frequency, a doc id, and a list of positions. Is that right? If so, you could use a dict of dicts:

```
dct = { 'wassup' : {
            'termfreq' : 'daily',
            'docid' : 1,
            'pos' : [3,4] }}
```

Then, given a term, like 'wassup', you could look up the term frequency with

```
dct['wassup']['termfreq']
# 'daily'
```

Think of a dict as being like a telephone book. It is great at looking up values (phone numbers) given keys (names). It is not so hot at looking up keys given values. Use a dict when you know you need to look things up in a one-way direction. You may need some other data structure (a database perhaps?) if your lookup patterns is more complex.

---

You might also want to check out the [Natural Language Toolkit (nltk)](http://www.nltk.org/). It has a [method for calculating `tf_idf`](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.text.TextCollection-class.html) built in:

```
import nltk

# Given a corpus of texts
text1 = 'Lorem ipsum FOO dolor BAR sit amet'
text2 = 'Ut enim ad FOO minim veniam, '
text3 = 'Duis aute irure dolor BAR in reprehenderit '
text4 = 'Excepteur sint occaecat BAR cupidatat non proident'

# We split the texts into tokens, and form a TextCollection
mytexts = (
    [nltk.word_tokenize(text) for text in [text1, text2, text3, text4]])
mycollection = nltk.TextCollection(mytexts)

# Given a new text
text = 'et FOO tu BAR Brute'
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

# for each token (roughly, word) in the new text, we compute the tf_idf
for word in tokens:
    print('{w}: {s}'.format(w = word,
                            s = mycollection.tf_idf(word,tokens)))
```

yields

```
et: 0.0
FOO: 0.138629436112
tu: 0.0
BAR: 0.0575364144904
Brute: 0.0
```

Comment: I am trying to build a pickle file that would allow me to implement textrank, tf-idf and search on a corpus of legal documents - so I suppose it goes in one way - from keys to values. Your solution seems to do the trick. Thanks a lot. (As this is my first week using python (actually programming in any language) I will probably be back in here in the near future:))

Comment: Thanks for the addition. I added bi- and trigrams to your code. Not sure where to post it though as it's a bit off topic.

Comment: If it is a new question, post a new question. If not, you could post it at https://gist.github.com/, and add a link here.

Comment: FYI, the gist link is broken.